# Redirect Specific Page to HTTPS Using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I'm trying to use .htaccess to redirect: http://shop.mysite.com/products/product-1 to https://shop.mysite.com/products/product-1 using .htaccess.  The only difference is the last part of the URL, the product name. I only want the redirect to be in affect for the products pages, nothing else.

Any tips?

Comment: **"The only difference is the last part of the URL, the product name. I only want the redirect to be in affect for the products pages, nothing else."**, The last part of both those URL's look exactly the same.

Comment: I'm sorry - what I meant was it will be a dynamic URL and the only difference between any of the product pages will be the last part, "product-x."  The first part "http://shop.mysite.com/products/" is always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?products/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/products/$1 [L,R=301]
```